# Capture photo using Webcam using Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a simple actionscript file with a webcam and an image. What I am looking to do is - when a button is clicked, I want to capture that instant of webcam  and image and render it in a DIV on the browser. How do I capture it? I am guessing the bitmapdata needs to be used. I want to do this via code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I wrote myself to answer this question. Tested in Chrome, FF and IE9.

You need Base64 encoder (one is [here](https://github.com/spjwebster/as3base64/blob/master/src/com/dynamicflash/util/Base64.as)) and png/jpg encoder (for example from Flex library).

**AS code:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    [SWF(width="640", height="480", backgroundColor="#000000")]
    public class CameraToJS extends Sprite
    {
        private var camera:Camera;
        private var video:Video;

        public function CameraToJS()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveSnapshot);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
            video =  new Video();
            video.attachCamera(camera);
            addChild(video);
        }

        protected function saveSnapshot(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var bmData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height);
            bmData.draw(video);

            var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();

            ExternalInterface.call("image", Base64.encodeByteArray(encoder.encode(bmData)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript code:**

```
function image(data)
{
    document.getElementById("img").src = "data:image/png;base64,"+ data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution Art. You are awesome! 

My requirement was slightly different and I was able to use a part of your solution with my existing code. Actually I had a bit of trouble with the encoder - turns out instead of creating an object encoder and using it in the next line, we should use PNGEncoder.encode(bmData) instead.

Also, the ExternalInterface was slightly troublesome because of some security settings which took me a while to figure out since I was using Chrome and it used to fail silently in Chrome. I saw the error in Firefox and fixed it.